# Add JS Reference to OrchardCore Module

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, orchard-modules

This is regarding the OrchardCore MVC
I have recently started learning OrchardCore MVC
Using .net core 3.1 I wanted to reference my custom JS file which I have created in my project
any help or any links will be helpful 
As simply drag and drop of the JS files are not working.
Thanks
Technology -
.net core MVC 3.1
Orchard Core  1.0.0-rc1-10004

Answer (score 0):

Best to override theme with your custom one or just override Layout page by templates and but your custom js in the new template